# Getting the previous and next 7 days from a specific date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

Getting the previous and next 7 days from a specific date

```
$date = new DateTime();
$today = $date->format('m d, Y');
```

How can I get the previous 7 and next 7 days from $today? and loop them in an array.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something different to the other answers but what about

```
$start   = new DateTime();
$end     = new DateTime();

$start   = $start->modify( '-7 days' ); 
$end     = $end->modify( '+8 days' ); // Date Period doesn't include the end date

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("'m d, Y'") . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Your example only gets the next 6 days, not what the Q asks for; but a good start. (There's also a glaring syntax error, at the time of writing this.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most suitable for this situation:

[`DateTime::modify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: +1 much better than creating a `TimeInterval` which to be used with `DateTime::add`.